# Flutter 3: Is there an in-build way to change window title and size of a desktop app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

With the release of Flutter 3, is there an in-build way to change window title and size of a desktop application without depending on external packages?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter 3.0 has no representation of a window, so does not currently provide any way to change window attributes directly.

> is there an in-build way to change window title and size of a desktop application without depending on external packages?

Technically the answer is yes, because you could write platform channel code directly in your application that does the same thing a plugin like [`window_size`](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/window_size) does. But you'd have to duplicate the work of writing the native code for each platform.

Assuming what you mean is whether you can do it entirely in Dart without using an external package, currently the answer is no.

Comment: Yes, what I actually meant is that it should be in Dart and also not a plugin/package but part of Flutter (out of the box) to avoid duplication.